# How to use $variables from one scss file to another

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass

I'm working with Angular 4 application. Below is my code looks like.

### variables.scss

```
$primary: blue;
$secondary: red;
```

Defining $variables.

### styles.scss

```
@import './assets/variables';
```

Importing variables.scss file in styles.scss

### angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ]
```

Importing styles.scss file in angular-cli.json so that whatever the imports in styles.scss file can use my entire project.

### header.html

```
<h1 class="primary-color">Header</h1>
```

Defined primary-color class in header.html file

### header.scss

```
.primary-color{
    color: $primary;
}
```

Trying to use $primary variable in header.scss file. But compiler throws me with error message as

> Undefined variable: "$primary".

I tried to import variables.scss file in header.scss file and now it works fine as it displays text "Header" in blue color. Now my header.scss file looks like below.

### header.scss

```
@import "~assets/variables.scss";
.primary-color{
    color: $primary;
}
```

Now my questions is why should we import again in header.scss file though we already imported in styles.scss file? I don't like to import in every scss page because I've to use those $variables in so many scss files. Any thoughts/alternate-ideas please?

Comment: Let me answer you with question. Why do you have to import modules over and over again in javascript files as well? Its just the way parser works, the end result will be truncated, so why is that bothering you? This way you know exact location from which you imported variables (in case you have many variables files)

Comment: What else is in your styles.scss? That's where I think you should be putting all your imports, in the required load order.

Comment: Yes codeth. I've all imports in order in styles.scss